# Using FFMPEG to overlay 2 concat-demux videos

Tags: ffmpeg

I am making a screen recording software that captures gestures/mouse moves as coordinates+timestamps, and would like to overlay those on the screen recording. I have a folder of "Frames" that have a red circle and the rest transparent that correspond to the gestures.

The way I initially got it working was to use concat-demux to generate a video of the gestures, and then I overlay it with ffmpeg by chromakeying out the black background and overlaying it, but that is very slow.

Is there a better/faster way to do it that maybe doesn't make an intermediate video that I have to chromakey? I have access to the timestamps of the gestures as well as the duration these frames should stay on screen.

my pipeline:

```
Screen Frames w/ Timestamps+durations --> Concat-demux --> ---------------------------+
                                                                                      |
Gesture Logs --> Frames w/ timestamp+duration --> Concat-demux ---> chromakey --+     |
                    (has transparency)        (loses transparency)              |     |
                                                                                V     V
                                                                               Overlay
                                                                                  |
                                                                                  V
                                                                             Final Video
```

[Example frame from gestures which is the foreground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXHkx.png)
(The white is transparent)

The background has no transparency as it is a computer background

The command I used to combine the videos I generated is:
`ffmpeg -i gestures.mp4 -i screen.mp4 -filter_complex '[0]chromakey=0x000000:.1[bk];[1][bk]overlay' output.mp4`

Comment: Show your command and the complete log. Share a frame from the background and a frame from the foreground.

Comment: I edited it to include the command I used to overlay and an example from from the overlay

Comment: How did you create `gestures.mp4`?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i gen_cat_demux.txt -r 24 -preset ultrafast -s 1080x2340 gestures.mp4` and the txt file just has `file` then `duration` commands for each frame

Comment: Why not do `ffmpeg -i screen.mp4 -f concat -i gen_cat_demux.txt -filter_complex "overlay=format=auto,format=yuv420p" output.mp4`

Comment: That produces a video with only the `screen.mp4` showing

Comment: Doing a lot of guesswork here since you haven't shown the complete log.